# Reorganize data in RDD and store in defined format

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a Sequence file of the format `(Int, Array[Byte])`, which I load into Spark. I'd like to store this information in the following format: `Seq[Seq[Array[Byte]]]`.

Each row in the Sequence file represents a message, with the key being a message ID. I'd like to group these messages in batches of 100 (let's call it a messageSet) and store it as a `Seq`.

Depending on the number of messages, I can have multiple messageSets originating from one Sequence file. To improve computation, I'd prefer to use mapPartitions but it's not mandatory.

```
Message = Array[Byte]
MessageSet = Seq[Array[Byte]]
MessageSets = Seq[Seq[Array[Byte]]] // Sequence File
```

I've tried the following:

```
val rdd = sc.sequenceFile[Int, Array[Byte]](path)

var messageSets: Seq[Seq[Array[Byte]]] = Nil
rdd.foreachPartition(iter => {
  var messageSet: Seq[Array[Byte]] = Nil
  iter.grouped(batchSize).foreach(mSet => messageSet :+= mSet.map(m => m._2).seq)
  messageSets :+= messageSet
})
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Error:(419, 58) type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[Object]
 required: Seq[Array[Byte]]
 iter.grouped(batchSize).foreach(mSet => messageSet :+= mSet.map(m => m._2).seq)
                                                          ^
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

**Metadata**

```
scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.8 -- Copyright 2002-2016, LAMP/EPFL

spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.1
      /_/
```

Comment: I have updated my code and revised my question @zero323.

Comment: It still couldn't work correctly even if you resolved type errors. This code is simply incorrect due to Spark architecture and processing model. This is explained in the linked answer.